# ReactJS remove bound event handlers in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am attempted to unbind an event listener in an ES6 react component. I'm not certain if this is the best approach or not.

```
export default class ProductDetail extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount() {
        this.boundKeyListener = this.keyListener.bind(this);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.boundKeyListener);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.boundKeyListener);
    }
    ...
}
```

Inside of `this.keylistener` I need to do an `this.setState({foo:'bar'})` and the only way I found to run the listener in the scope of the class is with `fn.bind()`.

My question is, do I really need to save the boundListener to a property? Or would

```
document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keyListener.bind(this));
```

be sufficient?

Comment: I'll support what the docs show: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Yeah with React.createClass the binding is taken care of for you. I was trying todo it in ES6 ``... extends React.Component``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or would
>
> ```
> document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keyListener.bind(this));
> ```
>
> be sufficient?

No it wouldn't. `.bind` returns a **new** function, so you would be trying to remove a different handler than you added.

```js
function foo() {}

console.log(foo.bind(null) === foo.bind(null));
```